# Cordova showing white screen when appis installed in 4.4.2 android version

Tags: html, cordova

Cordova   showing white screen  when app is installed in  4.4.2  android version devices and it is working  fine in ios devices and 4.4.2 android version device and in 4.4.2 it was  showing error in console **Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.Webstation.Osmosys" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="WebstationApp" android:screenOrientation="userPortrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: That error tends to happen when there is no internet connection.

Comment: Thanks Ronald , we are using wifi and it is working good all other apps in the  device are working fine , and we did one more app  using  cordova it was working  good in 4.4.2 also, i debugged the app using GapDebug in console i am getting the following message "resource interpreted as script but transferred with mime type plain/text"